# jquery formwizard stop form plugin (ajax) after first step

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I use jquery form wizard to show a form in two steps. Before proceeding to the second step I use the jquery form plugin to do an ajax validation of the form fields in step 1.

The problem I have is that the complete form is also posted using ajax. Instead of redirecting to another page showing the results, the results are fetched on the same page. How can I configure the form plugin to post the complete form not using ajax?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                            $("#Catering").formwizard({
            formPluginEnabled: true,
            validationEnabled: true,
            focusFirstInput : true,
            remoteAjax : {"first" : { // add a remote ajax call when moving next from the second step
                    url : "/validate",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    beforeSend : function(){alert("Starting validation.")},
                    complete : function(){alert("Validation complete.")},
                    success : function(data){
                    if(!(data.geldig)){ // change this value to false in validate.html to simulate successful validation
                    $("#status").fadeTo(500,1,function(){
                    $(this).html(data.errormessage)
                                    });
                            return false; //return false to stop the wizard from going forward to the next step (this will always happen)
                                    }
                            return true; //return true to make the wizard move to the next step
                            }
                    }},
                             }
                            );
            });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont mind expose your variabes throught URL in formoptions you can redirect to anywhere and the variables captured with the form are stored in $.param(data)

So i solved with this part

```
formOptions: {
    success: function(data){ $("#status").fadeTo(500,1,function(){ $(this).html("You are now registered!").fadeTo(5000, 0); 
    beforeSubmit: function(data){ 

        $("#data").html("data sent to the server: "+ $.param(data) );
        /*HERE YOU MADE THE REDIRECTION WITH THE VARIABLES THROUGHT URL*/
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com?"+$.param(data);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
 }
```

So beforeSubmit all that you are doing is redirect to anypage with the parameters with URL